# Colors in the admin page

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm using Solr 4.0 (release from Oct, 12) and using two shard cluster with shard replicas example from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud. In my ~cloud page I can see the cluster's chart, for some reason 3 of shards/replicas are green and one of them is red. Sometimes they look different - some of them are green, grey, etc...

Any ideas what does those colors mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Screen Shots](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12548107/SOLR-3915-screenshot.png) attached @ [SOLR-3915](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3915)